# Javascript doesn't generate email

Tags: javascript

I've coded some js into an Articulate Storyline file for a workshop. I'm trying to get the system to compile a number of variables and email the data to the user. When I click on the icon to generate the email I get nothing.

SET DATE CODE

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var monthName = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","Septemeber","October","November","December");
var dateVal = d.getDate().toString();
var delimeter = ", ";
var delimeter1 = " ";
var txtPostdate = ""
var lDigit = dateVal.charAt( dateVal.length-1);
if (lDigit =  = "1"){
    txtPostdate = "st";
}else if(lDigit =  = "2"){
    txtPostdate = "nd";
}else if(lDigit =  = "3"){
    txtPostdate = "rd";
}else{
    txtPostdate = "th";
}
var dateString = weekday[d.getDay()]+delimeter+monthName[(d.getMonth())]+delimeter1+dateVal+txtPostdate+delimeter+d.getFullYear();
var player  =  GetPlayer();
player.SetVar("SystemDate",dateString);
```

SEND EMAIL CODE

```
var player = GetPlayer();

var useremail = player.GetVar("email");

var subject ="My Fact Sheet - Optimizing Your Online Job Applications";

var firstname = player.GetVar("firstname");
var lastname = player.GetVar("lastname");
var street = player.GetVar("street1");
var address2 = player.GetVar("street2");
var city = player.GetVar("city");
var state = player.GetVar("state");
var zip = player.GetVar("zip");
var phone = player.GetVar("phone");
var cell = player.GetVar("cell");
var mymail = player.GetVar("mymail");
var phone = player.GetVar("phone");
var cell = player.GetVar("cell");
var school1 = player.GetVar("school1");
var s1city = player.GetVar("s1city");
var s1degree = player.GetVar("s1degree");
var s1date = player.GetVar("s1date");
var s1start = player.GetVar("s1start");
var school2 = player.GetVar("school2");
var s2city = player.GetVar("s2city");
var s2degree = player.GetVar("s2degree");
var s2start = player.GetVar("s2start");
var s2date = player.GetVar("s2date");
var school3 = player.GetVar("school3");
var s3city = player.GetVar("s3city");
var s3degree = player.GetVar("s3degree");
var s3date = player.GetVar("s3date");
var s3start = player.GetVar("s3start");
var e1title = player.GetVar("e1title");
var e1start = player.GetVar("e1start");
var e1end = player.GetVar("e1end");
var e1 = player.GetVar("e1");
var e1employer = player.GetVar("e1employer");
var e1city = player.GetVar("e1city");
var e1state = player.GetVar("e1state");
var e1zip = player.GetVar("e1zip");
var e1super = player.GetVar("e1super");
var e1phone = player.GetVar("e1phone");
var e1reason = player.GetVar("e1reason");
var e1startsalary = player.GetVar("e1startsalary");
var e1endsalary = player.GetVar("e1endsalary");
var e1accomplish = player.GetVar("e1accomplish");
var e2title = player.GetVar("e2title");
var e2start = player.GetVar("e2start");
var e2end = player.GetVar("e2end");
var e2 = player.GetVar("e2");
var e2employer = player.GetVar("e2employer");
var e2city = player.GetVar("e2city");
var e2state = player.GetVar("e2state");
var e2zip = player.GetVar("e2zip");
var e2super = player.GetVar("e2super");
var e2phone = player.GetVar("e2phone");
var e2reason = player.GetVar("e2reason");
var e2startsalary = player.GetVar("e2startsalary");
var e2endsalary = player.GetVar("e2endsalary");
var e2accomplish = player.GetVar("e2accomplish");
var e3title = player.GetVar("e3title");
var e3start = player.GetVar("e3start");
var e3end = player.GetVar("e3end");
var e3 = player.GetVar("e3");
var e3employer = player.GetVar("e3employer");
var e3city = player.GetVar("e3city");
var e3state = player.GetVar("e3state");
var e3zip = player.GetVar("e3zip");
var e3super = player.GetVar("e3super");
var e3phone = player.GetVar("e3phone");
var e3reason = player.GetVar("e3reason");
var e3startsalary = player.GetVar("e3startsalary");
var e3endsalary = player.GetVar("e3endsalary");
var e3accomplish = player.GetVar("e3accomplish");
var r1name = player.GetVar("r1name");
var r1company = player.GetVar("r1company");
var r1email = player.GetVar("r1email");
var r1phone = player.GetVar("r1phone");
var r2name = player.GetVar("r2name");
var r2company = player.GetVar("r2company");
var r2email = player.GetVar("r2email");
var r2phone = player.GetVar("r2phone");
var r3name = player.GetVar("r3name");
var r3company = player.GetVar("r3company");
var r3email = player.GetVar("r3email");
var r3phone = player.GetVar("r3phone");
var cover = player.GetVar("cover");
var resume = player.GetVar("resume");
var mail = player.GetVar("mail");

var mailto_link='mailto:'+useremail+'?subject='+subject+'&body='+"Activity Notes – Optimizing Your Online Job Applications %0d%0A %0d%0AMy Name:%0d%0A”+firstname+”%0d%0A”+lastname+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Address:%0d%0A”+street1+”%0d%0A”+street2+”%0d%0A”+city+”%0d%0A”+state+”%0d%0A”+zip+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Home Phone: %0d%0A"+phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Cell Phone: %0d%0A”+cell+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy eMail: %0d%0A "+mymail+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Education:%0d%0A”+school1+”%0d%0A”+s1city+”+s1degree+”%0d%0A”+s1start+”%0d%0A”+s1date+”%0d%0A%0d%0A”+school2+”%0d%0A”+s2city+”%0d%0A”+s2degree+”%0d%0A“+s1start+”%0d%0A”+s2date+”%0d%0A%0d%0A”+school3+”%0d%0A“+s3city+”%0d%0A“+s3degree+”%0d%0A“+s1start+”%0d%0A“+s3date+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Employment History - Job 1: %0d%0A“+e1title+”%0d%0A%0d%0ADates: %0d%0A “+e1start+”%0d%0A“+e1end+”%0d%0A%0d%0AEmployer Information:%0d%0A“+e1+”%0d%0A“+e1employer+”%0d%0A“+e1city+”%0d%0A“+e1state+”%0d%0A“+e1zip+”%0d%0A%0d%0ACompany Contact: %0d%0A“+e1super+”%0d%0A“+e1phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0AReason for Leaving: %0d%0A“+e1reason+”%0d%0A%0d%0AStarting Salary: “+e1startsalary+”%0d%0AEnding Salary: ”+e1endsalary+”%0d%0A%0d%0AAccomplishments:%0d%0A“+e1accomplish+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Employment History - Job 2:%0d%0A“+e2title+”%0d%0A%0d%0ADates:%0d%0A“+e2start+”%0d%0A“+e2end+”%0d%0A%0d%0AEmployer Information: %0d%0A“+e2+”%0d%0A“+e2employer+”%0d%0A“+e2city+”%0d%0A“+e2state+”%0d%0A“+e2zip+”%0d%0A%0d%0ACompany Contact: %0d%0A“+e2super+”%0d%0A“+e2phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0AReason for Leaving:%0d%0A“+e2reason+”%0d%0A%0d%0AStarting Salary: “+e2startsalary+”%0d%0AEnding Salary: “+e2endsalary+”%0d%0A%0d%0AAccomplishments:%0d%0A“+e2accomplish+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Employment History - Job 3:%0d%0A“+e3title+”%0d%0A%0d%0ADates:%0d%0A“+e3start+”%0d%0A“+e3end+”%0d%0A%0d%0AEmployer Information:%0d%0A
“+e3+”%0d%0A“+e3employer+”%0d%0A“+e3city+”%0d%0A“+e3state+”%0d%0A“+e3zip+”%0d%0A%0d%0ACompany Contact:%0d%0A“+e3super+”%0d%0A“+e3phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0AReason for Leaving:%0d%0A“+e3reason+”%0d%0A%0d%0AStarting Salary: “+e3startsalary+”%0d%0AEnding Salary: “+e3endsalary+”%0d%0A%0d%0AAccomplishments:%0d%0A“+e3accomplish+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy References:%0d%0A“+r1name+”%0d%0A“+r1company+”%0d%0A“+r1email+”%0d%0A“+r1phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0A“+r2name+”%0d%0A“+r2company+”%0d%0A“+r2email+”%0d%0A“+r2phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0A“+r3name+”%0d%0A“+r3company+”%0d%0A“+r3email+”%0d%0A“+r3phone+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Resume:%0d%0A“+resume+”%0d%0A%0d%0AMy Cover Letter:%0d%0A“+cover+”%0d%0A%0d%0A

win=window.open(mailto_link,'emailWin');
```

Comment: *"When I click on the icon to generate the email I get nothing."* - Not even an error in the browser's debug console? Is all of that code inside a function?

Comment: I'm using an eLearning software program, I can only see it after I upload to the web because java does not work in preview.

Comment: The second last line with `var mailto_link = ...` seems to have some "smart quote" characters (`“` and `”`) in it - is that in your real code? I'd start by replacing those with "normal" double-quote characters (`"`).

Comment: Java? You mean JavaScript?

Comment: SEND EMAIL CODE made my eyes bleeding :(

Comment: Sorry Robo and Thanks Rob, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Gah! Still nothing. No response on click. JS showing me no love.

Comment: What program is this that you are using? maybe you should put it in the tags so you can get help from people more familiar with debugging in that environment.

Comment: Also, note that links cannot contain spaces, but your mailto link does (eg "Activity Notes", and likely in the subject, etc). Oh, also not sure whats going on there, but those aren't quotation marks but some special characters `”%0d%0A“`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting %20 in place of spaces. Text in the submitted URL has spaces "Activity Notes – Optimizing Your Online.........". I did not survey the entire URL, but be sure to encode wherever needed.

Comment: Thanks dmc... i tried your recommendations, but still nothing. i don't understand; i used a similar code in another workshop and it functions as it should. aaaargh!

Comment: You may not have the email program registered properly on the workstation to service mailto: .

Comment: i think i just need to hang it up for the night. lol. my eyeballs are ready to sink into my skull. i tried another machine, still nothing.

Comment: I noticed "var subject ="My Fact Sheet - ....." at top. Did you take care of spaces in that, too?